# rails helpers location

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I made a simple helper with one function and put it in the relevant controller_helper and I noticed that the function is valid from the whole application views.

Why is that? shouldn't the helper be valid only to his controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The process is the following:

If you're in a view belonging to controller `foo` and you call a helper called `my_helper`:

- if defined in `foo`'s helper, it's executed from here
- if not defined in `foo`'s helper but defined in another helper, say `bar`, it's executed from there
- if not in `foo` nor in any `bar`, it's checked in `application_helper`. If it doesn't exist here, an error is raised.

Answer (score 0):

That would make sense, but it's not the complete story.  I have a controller `MainController` and a controller `AlsoController`, and defined a helper with the same name `wherefrom` in each of the helper modules ie `MainHelper` and `AlsoHelper`.  But if I try to make use of `wherefrom` in the `also` view, it uses the helper defined in `MainHelper` instead of the one in `AlsoHelper`.

Comment: (What is it that would make sense?) ... It seems strange that the preferred method would be one in a different helper.  Is there something magic about the Main controller?